# UncaughtbTypeError: (0 , _redux2.default) is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying to use react-redux,but getting this error

> UncaughtbTypeError: (0 , _redux2.default) is not a function

Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import Provider from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import reducer from './src/reducers/Index';
import Root from './src/views/Root';

let store = createStore(reducer)

ReactDom.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Root />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Reducer (Index.js)

```
import combineReducers from 'redux';
import Login from './Login';

const reducer = combineReducers({
    Login
})

export default reducer
```

Reducer (Login.js)

```
export default function login(state = [], action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'LOGINLOADING':
            return false
        case 'LOGINLOADED':
            return true
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Comment: In Reducer (Index.js), change the import statement to import { combineReducers } from "redux"

Comment: try import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

Comment: i have the same issue and my combineReducers is mport { combineReducers } from 'redux';. does anyone have any solution ?